# count associate rows in multiple tables with left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select `Posts` with the associate numbers of `Comments` and `Likes`.

This is my query

```
SELECT `waller_posts`.*,
       COUNT(waller_comments.id) AS num_comments,
       COUNT(waller_likes.id) AS num_likes
FROM `waller_posts`
LEFT JOIN `waller_comments` ON `waller_comments`.`post_id` = `waller_posts`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `waller_likes` ON `waller_likes`.`post_id` = `waller_posts`.`id`
WHERE `wall_id` = 1
  AND `wall_type` = "User"
GROUP BY `waller_posts`.`id`
```

When I add the second `left join` in this case of the `likes`, the results of the `num_comments` and `num_likes` came wrong. How can I perform this kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query builds up to give you every possible combination of comments and likes on a post.

Probably easiest to just use COUNT(DISTINCT...) :-

```
SELECT `waller_posts`.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT waller_comments.id) AS num_comments,
       COUNT(DISTINCT waller_likes.id) AS num_likes
FROM `waller_posts`
LEFT JOIN `waller_comments` ON `waller_comments`.`post_id` = `waller_posts`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `waller_likes` ON `waller_likes`.`post_id` = `waller_posts`.`id`
WHERE `wall_id` = 1
  AND `wall_type` = "User"
GROUP BY `waller_posts`.`id`
```

Note that your query is relying on a feature of MySQL but which would cause an error in most flavours of SQL. For most flavours of SQL you need to list ALL the non aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This seem to work!! I just tried on my sql editor, give me a couple of minutes to test it thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Distinct` clause because it will display combination of like and comment table data

```
SELECT `waller_posts`.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT waller_comments.id) AS num_comments,
       COUNT(DISTINCT waller_likes.id) AS num_likes
FROM `waller_posts`
LEFT JOIN `waller_comments` ON `waller_comments`.`post_id` = `waller_posts`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `waller_likes` ON `waller_likes`.`post_id` = `waller_posts`.`id`
WHERE `wall_id` = 1
  AND `wall_type` = "User"
GROUP BY `waller_posts`.`id`
```

Comment: Have understand my answer if any query let me know. I explain it.

Comment: Thanks Sadikhsan really kind but I even tried how you said but the result come exactly the same to my query.